# how to check a date is in current financial year

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, plsql, where-clause

I am trying to check a condition if given date is in current financial year i.e april to march. but not getting any idea how to do

code

```
select nvl(Count(1), 0)+1 from ASET where IPE='O' and irt in (SELECT    EXTRACT (YEAR FROM ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, -3))
       || '-'
       || EXTRACT (YEAR FROM ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, 9))
  FROM DUAL)
```

irt is date 01-09-2020.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest approach is to offset the date column and `sysdate` by 3 months, and compare the year part:

```
where to_char(add_months(irt, -3), 'yyyy') = to_char(add_months(sysdate, -3), 'yyyy')
```